# SQL Server DB Restore Clustered to Single Node?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, restore, clustering

Can you restore a DB from a SQL Server 2005 Clustered Environment (Prod) to a single server (single node) (SQL Server 2005) in Dev/Sys?

Cheers,
Conor

Comment: Closing as I got answer from in-house DBA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The clustered production SQL Server instance should be transparent to the database